# How to get all the column number and row number of DTED file

Tags: raster, gdal, c++, dted

I am not very familiar with GDAL. I use this coding to get all the 3601*3601 elevation value into an vector array.The issues that it only show elevation point and not the row and column. How can I get the number of column and row that align with that elevation point?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const char* pszFilename = "C:\\ElevationSample.DT2";
    double adfGeoTransform[6];
    float buffEleveationValue[1];
    

     int rows = 3601;
     int columns = 3601;


    std::vector<float> buffElevation(rows * columns);

    

    int row;
    int col;

    GDALRasterBand *poBand;

    GDALDataset  *poDataset;
    GDALAllRegister();
    poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen( pszFilename, GA_ReadOnly );

    printf( "Driver: %s/%s\n",
        poDataset->GetDriver()->GetDescription(),
        poDataset->GetDriver()->GetMetadataItem( GDAL_DMD_LONGNAME ) );
    printf( "Size is %dx%dx%d\n",
        poDataset->GetRasterXSize(),poDataset->GetRasterYSize(),
        poDataset->GetRasterCount() );
    if( poDataset->GetProjectionRef()  != NULL )
        printf( "Projection is `%s'\n", poDataset->GetProjectionRef() );
    if( poDataset->GetGeoTransform( adfGeoTransform ) == CE_None )
    {
        printf( "Origin = (%.6f,%.6f)\n",
                adfGeoTransform[0], adfGeoTransform[3] );
        printf( "Pixel Size = (%.6f,%.6f)\n",
                adfGeoTransform[1], adfGeoTransform[5] );
    }



    poDataset->GetGeoTransform(adfGeoTransform);
    poBand = poDataset->GetRasterBand(1); 


    poBand->RasterIO(GF_Read, 0, 0, columns,rows, buffElevation.data(),columns,rows, GDT_Float32, 0, 0); // read the cell value
    
            getchar();

            return 0;
    /*  }
    }*/
    
}
```